# Trouble updating log with triggers using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I am trying to create a trigger with a higher difficulty that would let me create a log after updating rows in alumns table

```
| Alumn_ID | Name   |  Courses    | Favourite_Course
      1       Peter       5                Math
```

And this would be the result if for example someone updated the number of courses from 5 to 6.

```
| Log_ID | Alumn_ID |   Note            | NoteID  | Change_Date            | Last_Change_Date
     1          1     Fields were Updated Note 1    2018-04-23 00:00:00.000  2018-03-23 00:00:00.000
```

Here is my current trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [LOG]
ON ALUMNS
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Note VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE @Alumn_ID varchar;
SELECT @Alumn_ID= INSERTED.Alumn_ID FROM INSERTED

SET @Note = 'Fields were updated'

INSERT INTO Alumn_Log (Log_ID, Alumn_ID, Note, NoteID, Change_Date)
SELECT Log_ID, i.Alumn_ID, @Note, NoteID, GETDATE(); FROM INSERTED i
END
```

My problem is:

- How do i create the Log ID and the Note ID that i can't take from INSERTED i?
- My second problem is, how do i insert the current date? when i try to execute the query it tells me that i can't use that variable in INSERTS.

  - My third problem, is how can i put the "Last change date"?
  - Fourth, is there a way to type an specific Note for example if only the name was changed it should say "Name was changed"?
- Finally, The Note ID would be Varchar not identity and every note ID needs to be different

This is the current and only error that's preventing me from running the Query:

This is what i get Msg 273, level 16, state 1, procedure Log_Trigger, line 19 [Batch Start Line 0] me time stamp Use INSERT with a list of columns to exclude the timestamp column or insert DEFAULT in the timestamp column.

Comment: You're making a rookie mistake in your trigger code. Triggers fire for more than one row. If you do an UPDATE with a WHERE clause that isn't a primary key, your INSERTED collection is going to have EVERY row that is getting updated. So your statements simply won't do what you're thinking (they'll only insert for the last row in INSERTED, not every row). You must use SET operations, not scalar variables trying to select out one column value.

Comment: @pmbAustin not exactly.. he makes this mistake when populating `@Alumn_ID`, but then `@Alumn_ID` never gets used in the rest of the code, so the end effect doesn't suffer from this mistake.  He joins to the `INSERTED` table in the final log insert.   The `@Alumn_ID` lines are just useless lines that can be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would approach it.

- How do i create the Log ID and the Note ID that i can't take from
  INSERTED i?

*The Log Id can be an AutoIdentity column. An INT column with IDENTITY INSERT.
The Note ID can be an Auto Incremented Computed column (shown in the code below). You would probably need to introduce a new column that serves as a prefix.*

- My second problem is, how do i insert the current date? when i try to
  execute the query it tells me that i can't use that variable in
  INSERTS.

*GETDATE()?*

- My third problem, is how can i put the "Last change date"?

*You can have a join with INSERTED and get the value from the log from a previous row. Shown in the code.*

- Fourth, is there a way to type an specific Note for example if only
  the name was changed it should say "Name was changed"?

  *That would depend on finding the nature of the update on which column. This is more of a business question than a technical question.*

Finally, The Note ID would be Varchar not identity and every note ID needs to be different

Now, the code (the entire schema)

```js
CREATE TABLE LOG(
  Log_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  Alumn_ID INT,
  NOTE VARCHAR(200),
  PREFIX VARCHAR(30),
  NOTEID AS([PREFIX] + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(Log_ID AS VARCHAR(7)), 7)) PERSISTED,
  CHANGEDATE DATETIME,
  LASTCHANGEDATE DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE ALUMN(
  Alumn_ID INT,
  NAME VARCHAR(50),
  COURSES INT,
  FAVORITE_COURSE VARCHAR(50)
);



CREATE TRIGGER[trg_LOG]
ON ALUMN
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Note VARCHAR(50)

  --DECLARE @Alumn_ID VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Lastchange DATETIME
--SELECT @Alumn_ID = INSERTED.Alumn_ID FROM INSERTED

SET @Note = 'Fields were updated'

SELECT @Lastchange = CHANGEDATE FROM LOG l
INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON l.Alumn_ID = i.Alumn_ID
  --INNER JOIN ALUMN

INSERT INTO LOG(Alumn_ID, Note, Prefix, CHANGEDATE, LASTCHANGEDATE)
SELECT i.Alumn_ID, @Note, 'AUP', GETDATE(), @Lastchange FROM INSERTED i
END
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the LOG_ID field already exists and it is Varchar(20) in the table ALUMN

Answer (score 0):

> how do i insert the current date? when i try to execute the query it
>   tells me that i can't use that variable in INSERTS.

```
SELECT Log_ID, i.Alumn_ID, @Note, NoteID, GETDATE(); FROM INSERTED i
```

Take the semi-colon out of the line above.

```
SELECT Log_ID, i.Alumn_ID, @Note, NoteID, GETDATE() FROM INSERTED i
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for the date, but how can i declare the Log_ID and the Note ID to be insertet automatically?

Comment: Depends what you want them to be.

Comment: i tried that but when i executed the query it tells me that i can't insert explicit values into a column with time. That i should use insert to exclude or use default

Comment: Please provide enough information to reproduce this error, there is not enough information here to help you further than this.

Comment: This is what i get

Msg 273, level 16, state 1, procedure Log_Trigger, line 19 [Batch Start Line 0]
me time stamp Use INSERT with a list of columns to exclude the timestamp column or insert DEFAULT in the timestamp column.

Comment: You didn't get that error from the code you posted in the question.   Edit the question and put your actual code in it, or we can't help you.